# ace:dateTimeEntry's value within ui:repeat reappearing and/or not clearing via ace:ajax on manual entry

Tags: ajax, jsf, icefaces-3

I recreated the [ace:dateTimeEntry - AJAX Submit Example](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dateAjax) and was successful; however, once I wrap the ace:dateTimeEntry within an ui:repeat, functionality seems to stop.

**Overall Issue:**
When within the ui:repeat, the value of the ace:dateTimeEntry and ice:outputText will reappear if a user tabs out of the cal_input (of the ace:dateTimeEntry) OR submits the form even after the AJAX dateTextChangeListener fires (witnessed via System.out statements).
The id of all components were located via FireBug and/or Firefox inspect element and were put into the ajax as other posts instructed - however, still no luck.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

---

**Environment Information**
-ICEFaces 3.3.0
-JSF 2.0
-JBoss Application Server

**Directory Structure**
-layout.xhtml
--main.xhtml (has the `<ice:form>`)
---date.xhtml

---

**Date.xhtml - Not Working Example**

```
 <div>
  <ui:repeat id="toast" value="#{backingBean.currentDetails}" var="row">
   <ace:panel>

    <ice:panelGrid width="100%">
     <ice:panelGroup>
      <ice:outputLabel for="text" value="Selected Date: "/>
      <ice:outputText id="text" value="#{backingBean.selectedDate}">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="MMMM dd, yyyy"/>
      </ice:outputText>
    </ice:panelGroup>

    <ice:panelGrid width="100%">
     <ace:dateTimeEntry id="cal" value="#{backingBean.selectedDate}">
      renderAsPopup="true"
      timeZone="Canada/Mountain"
      pattern="MMM/dd/yyyy">
       <ace:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{backingBean.dateSelectListener" render=":mainForm:toast:0:cal :mainForm:toast:0:text"/>
       <ace:ajax event="dateTextChange" listener="#{backingBean.dateTextChangeListener" render=":mainForm:toast:0:cal :mainForm:toast:0:text"/>
      </ace:dateTimeEntry>
     </ice:panelGrid>

    </ace:panel>
   </ui:repeat>
  </div>
```

**Date.xhtml - Working Example**

```
<div>
 <ace:panel>

  <ice:panelGrid width="100%">
   <ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:outputLabel for="text" value="Selected Date: "/>
    <ice:outputText id="text" value="#{backingBean.selectedDate}">
     <f:convertDateTime pattern="MMMM dd, yyyy"/>
    </ice:outputText>
   </ice:panelGroup>

  <ice:panelGrid width="100%">
   <ace:dateTimeEntry id="cal" value="#{backingBean.selectedDate}">
    renderAsPopup="true"
    timeZone="Canada/Mountain"
    pattern="MMM/dd/yyyy">
     <ace:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{backingBean.dateSelectListener" render="@this text"/>
     <ace:ajax event="dateTextChange" listener="#{backingBean.dateTextChangeListener" render="@this text"/>
    </ace:dateTimeEntry>
   </ice:panelGrid>

  </ace:panel>
 </div>
```

---

**Listeners**

```
public void dateSelectListener(DateSelectEvent event)
 {
  this.selectedDate = event.getDate();
 }

public void dateTextChangeListener(DateTextChangeEvent event)
 {
  this.selectedDate = event.getDate();
 }
```

---

***Note***
I have used Firefox's Inspect element to look at the id's and attempt to have them point back; however, that has been unsuccessful. Also, the console output affirms the correct id when inserting a value that cannot convert (such as abc)

I changed @this to... :mainForm:toast:0:cal (also tried cal_input)
I changed text to... :mainForm:toast:0:text

I've also tried..
:mainForm:toast
Wrapping the ui:repeat within an h:panelGroup with an id.
Switching to an h:dataTable

Also, on several occasions I was able to have the input field remain blank, but on form submit - the value is populated.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the ui:repeat with h:dataTable, wrapped the ace:panel with an h:column, and removed all ace:ajax. The ace:dateTimeEntry now works as expected.